# How to move 2D camera in OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 2d

I am new in OpenGL, I am making a game in 2D and I want the camera to follow the character.

I started with gluLookAt() but I read that I could just move the matrix with glTranslatef() and It should do the trick.

The problem is the camera only move the first time It is created but if I increment the X position and Y position It doesn't work. What I m doing wrong? I have incorrect concepts?

I tried it changing to GL_PROJECTION,GL_MODELVIEW, AND GL_TEXTURE,

If I do it on GL_PROJECTION all the items are gone ( thanks to the question answer link I understand that I cant take that way)

If I do it on GL_TEXTURE all the textures start to scroll ( but that is not what i want

If I do it on GL_MODELVIEW just nothing happen all the item are in the same site but if I quit the gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW) line above translatef It move the camera the first iteration and then stop to do it since the last object is on GL10.GL_MODELVIEW

Is at the start at different matrix state?
This is how it seem with initials values of X = 0 and Y = 0
[image]

This is how it seem with initials values of X = -2 and Y = -2 and ELIMINATING gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW)  ( If i dont elimiate this line, it seems like the first one even with the values -2)

[image]

On both cases the camera doesnt move, just stay on that position

My render code:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    loopStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try
    {
        if (loopRunTime < SEngine.GAME_THREAD_FPS_SLEEP)
        {
            Thread.sleep(SEngine.GAME_THREAD_FPS_SLEEP - loopRunTime);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
    }
    deltaTime = (float) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - aRestar)/1000f);


    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClearColor((78.0f / 255.0f), (192.0f / 255.0f), (203.0f / 255.0f), 0.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);

    perro.move(gl);
    moversetas(gl);
    palmera.draw(gl);




    comprobacionesColision();
    actualizar(deltaTime);

    x +=0.05f;
    y +=0.05f;

    loopEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    loopRunTime = ((loopEnd - loopStart));

}
```

Comment: I would suggest not using the glTranslatef type functions and instead use shaders

Comment: Just curious.. why don't you learn opengl es 2.0?

Comment: I didnt find any good guide to learn openGL es 2.0, if you know about anyone and can give me a link it will be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a lot of tries I made it,Stil I dont know if this is the best way to achieve this, if someone can explain why this is a solution it will be good!

I just change the matrix  mode to GL_PROJECTION and translate it

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0f, 8f, 0f, 4f, -1f, 1f);
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);
```

instead of

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is tricky to work with. Do you have any knowledge on how to work with one?
Also, 0.05f increments are quite small, have you tried larger steps? The rest of your code seems fine to me.
Also, are you in GL_PROJECTION or GL_MODELVIEW? Take a look at this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/how-do-i-position-a-2d-camera-in-opengl Just look at the bottom answer.

Comment: I have so basic knowledge of it, I try it changing to GL_PROJECTION,GL_MODELVIEW, AND GL_TEXTURE,

The question is update with the result of changing the matrix models

Thanks for the link it was so usefull

Comment: It's also usually a specific order on which to draw/activate first; one of the tricky things about programming for games :]
Also, is your camera's rotation-matrix set-up properly? Are you sure it's looking at the character?

Comment: What you mean your with camera's rotation matrix set up?, Actually is not looking at the character, just trying to move the camera(but it doesn't move), The order should be fine because the first iteration works

Comment: @D4rWiNS WHat I meant by that is: Does your camera look in the right direction? Your camera could be looking at 0,0 (up, I think) whereas it has to look at for instance: 3,4.
Also, have you tried bigger steps for the movement, yet? Just to exagerate: 7.0f?

Comment: I think that is looking in the right direction because I see the object, I update the question with photos to be more clear

Comment: I added an answer as solution could you tell me if it is a good solution?

Comment: @D4rWiNS I can't reply to the solution you posted for some reason, so I'll do it here: If it works, that's good! GL_PROJECTION is generally used for transforming the camera, whereas GL_MODELVIEW is used for transforming the objects on screen. I only just read it, so I feel silly myself too. Good luck in your future endeavours!